# VBA Adding Custom Object in Collection to Temp Variable

Tags: excel, vba, collections, bubble-sort

So I've followed some examples Ive seen on sorting items in a collection, but for some reason when I try to store an element I a temporary variable I get a warning from vba "Object doesn't support this property or method", I set the temp variable to variant but it doesn't seem to care. Could it be an issue with my object type?

```
 Sub selectRange()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim streamColl As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim columnCount As Integer
    Dim tempStream As Stream

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Range("E5").Select

    lastrow = Range("E5", ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Count + 5
    lastColumn = Range("E5", ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Count

    Set streamColl = New Collection

    For i = 1 To lastColumn
            Set tempStream = New Stream
                tempStream.StreamName = Cells(3, i + 4).value
                tempStream.Temperature = Cells(5, i + 4).value
                tempStream.Pressure = Cells(6, i + 4).value
                tempStream.VapGasFlow = Cells(7, i + 4).value
                tempStream.VapMW = Cells(8, i + 4).value
                tempStream.VapZFactor = Cells(9, i + 4).value
                tempStream.VapViscosity = Cells(10, i + 4).value
                tempStream.LightLiqVolFlow = Cells(11, i + 4).value
                tempStream.LightLiqMassDensity = Cells(12, i + 4).value
                tempStream.LightLiqViscosity = Cells(13, i + 4).value
                tempStream.HeavyLiqVolFlow = Cells(14, i + 4).value
                tempStream.HeavyLiqMassDensity = Cells(15, i + 4).value
                tempStream.HeavyLiqViscosity = Cells(16, i + 4).value
                streamColl.Add tempStream
    Next
    MsgBox streamColl(1).StreamName
    Call sortStream(streamColl) 
End Sub

Sub sortStream(ByVal pStreamColl As Collection)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim vTemp as variant



  lastColumn = 0
  k = 1
  Do While IsNumeric(pStreamColl(k).StreamName)
    lastColumn = lastColumn + 1
    k = k + 1
  Loop

  MsgBox lastColumn

  For i = 1 To lastColumn
    For j = i + 1 To lastColumn
        If pStreamColl(j).StreamName < pStreamColl(i).StreamName Then
            vTemp = pStreamColl(j)


            pStreamColl.Remove j
            pStreamColl.Add vTemp, vTemp, i
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For Each Stream In pStreamColl
    Debug.Print Stream.StreamName
Next Stream
End sub
```

the error gets thrown on the line

```
vtemp = pStreamColl(j)
```

Would using an array be better?

Comment: Use `Set vTemp = ...` to store objects.

Comment: Now the error is thrown on pstreamcoll.add vtemp vtemp I

When I remove j, does that break the reference to vtemp?

Comment: The "key" of the collection has to be a string, you cannot pass an object as a key. Maybe use vTemp.StreamName?

Comment: If the keys are numbers that are strings how do I sort them then?

Comment: I don't believe you can sort a Collection based on its keys.  The keys are not accessible. You need to sort based on the collection item.

Answer (score 0):

### Stream()

You could use an Array of Streams

```
ReDim Streams(1 To lastColumn) As New Stream

For i = 1 To lastColumn
    With Streams(i)
        .StreamName = Cells(3, i + 4).Value
        .Temperature = Cells(5, i + 4).Value
        .Pressure = Cells(6, i + 4).Value
        .VapGasFlow = Cells(7, i + 4).Value
        .VapMW = Cells(8, i + 4).Value
        .VapZFactor = Cells(9, i + 4).Value
        .VapViscosity = Cells(10, i + 4).Value
        .LightLiqVolFlow = Cells(11, i + 4).Value
        .LightLiqMassDensity = Cells(12, i + 4).Value
        .LightLiqViscosity = Cells(13, i + 4).Value
        .HeavyLiqVolFlow = Cells(14, i + 4).Value
        .HeavyLiqMassDensity = Cells(15, i + 4).Value
        .HeavyLiqViscosity = Cells(16, i + 4).Value
    End With
Next
```

### Use StrComp to sort Strings

> ```
>  Function StrComp(String1, String2, [Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare])
> ```

Reference: [How to use the STRCOMP Function (VBA)](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strcomp.php)

```
Sub sortStream(ByRef Streams() As Stream)
    Dim swapped As Boolean, st As Stream
    Dim n As Long
    Do
        swapped = False
        For n = LBound(Streams) + 1 To UBound(Streams)
            If StrComp(Streams(n - 1).StreamName, Streams(n).StreamName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Set st = Streams(n - 1)
                Set Streams(n - 1) = Streams(n)
                Set Streams(n) = st
                swapped = True
            End If
        Next
    Loop Until Not swapped

End Sub
```

I only suggested the `Stream()` because I wanted to write a Bubble Sort.  I would use a `SortedList`.

### SortedList

[MSDN SortedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted by the keys and are accessible by key and by index.

Additional Reference:[VBA SortedList](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Sortedlist_en.html)

You will need to make these changes to use a `SortedList`:

Before

```
Dim streamColl As Collection
Set streamColl = New Collection  
streamColl.Add tempStream
```

After

```
Dim streamColl As Object
Set streamColl = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
streamColl.Add Key:=tempStream.StreamName, Value:=tempStream.
```

Comment: Yeah I decided to go with an array but I'll have to try the sorted list.  I don't have very much data so I thought bubble would work for now. Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to use a `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` and sort it by its keys. Dictionaries are easier to work with then SortedLists.  Good Luck!